# language internationalization in a flutter App

Tags: flutter, localization, internationalization

I have taken a look at some of flutter plugins regarding this issue but the problem is I would always still need to create a JSON file for whatever language I want to use in my App.
I was wondering if there is any open source API or a plug-in that could save me the efforts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `VSCode` then the `flutter_intl` plugin might be for you. If you don't know multiple languages or you don't want to type all of the strings manually then you can use `Localizely` website which helps in collaboration of people who can translate the strings to different or their own native languages
They also have an API which can be used to fetch all of those translations to your app straightaway

[Here](https://roszkowski.dev/2021/i18n-in-flutter/) is a nice article that explains how to do it

Comment: Thanks for the answer! the Link doesn't work though. could you share it again, please?